# Create Query With Symfony and ElasticaSearch using "AND" and "OR" operators

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'd like to create a query with elasticasearch like this :

```
(user1 OR user2) AND place
```

here is my script :

```
<?php


$boolQuery  = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();

$search     = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString($nameTerm);

$search->setFields(array("name"));

$boolQuery->addShould($search);

$boolQuery   = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();
$search1     = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString($nameTerm1);

$search1->setFields(array("name"));

$boolQuery->addShould($search1);


$search3 = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString($citieTerm);
$search3->setFields(array("address.libelle"));

$boolQuery->addMust($search3);


$filtered   = new \Elastica\Query\Filtered($boolQuery);
$query      = \Elastica\Query::create($filtered);

$result     = $this->find($query);

?>
```